# How can I tell if BitLocker is successfully enabled on remote hosts?

Tags: bitlocker

All machines from my network should have BitLocker successfully applied to them.

Is there a way that I can remotely query the machines to see if:

1. Bitlocker has been enabled,
2. Bitlocker has fully encrypted the drive.

Ideally I am looking for a way to do it without admin rights.

Answer (score 15):

With this PowerShell command, you can check the BitLocker status on a volume:

```
Manage-bde -status -cn <computername/ip> <drive letter>
```

Where the `-cn` argument is optional. Examples:

```
Manage-bde -status C:
Manage-bde -status -cn 192.168.1.2 C:
```

The command can also be run remotely.

Reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff829849(v=ws.11)

Comment: This seems to be not working without admin rights.

Comment: This doesn't work on a large majority of Dell machines I maintain...

Answer (score 11):

For a remote host:

```
manage-bde -status -computername **computername**
```

Answer (score 8):

That is the command that gives the information you need.

```
Manage-bde -status C:
```

[image: A screenshot of a console window, showing the output of the "manage-bde -status c:" command.]

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer on our site. It would be highly beneficial to summarise what exactly is in the image you posted, so that users with vision impairments can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 4):

```
manage-bde -status -computername "COMPUTERNAME" c:
```

The computer must be on and on the network however, does not work for machines out of network or that are off.

Comment: also this will not query all drives, notice the c: that is just for the drive, for multiple drives I recommend querying the drives and then using the last part as a variable with a for each loop

Comment: the answer above that forgoes the C: will query multiple drives